# Help! The help centre is full of nonsense!

Tags: bug, help-center

### All the help centre pages seem to be broken.

- [Be Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) looks like this:

  [image: Be Nice screenshot]
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) looks like this:

  [image: On-topic screenshot from SFF]

  It's also [different](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [different](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sites, but always nonsense.

What gives? Did April Fool's come early?

Comment: @KazWolfe Gah. That's what happens when there's a network-wide bug and everyone posts to main meta at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I got hit by the dupe-hammer for a post 15 seconds late, so I know the feel.